# Facebook Graph - get Posts, checking if message contains string

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Im trying to read the facebook posts from our wall and we decided we dont want all of the posts, we just want some of them. So basicly our idea was to add a special keyword (for example: "#keyword") to each post, and then simply search for all posts that contains the keyword. I dont know if theres a smarter solution, if there is any let me know :)

What i used before:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<OurID>/posts?limit=15&access_token=<privateToken>
```

Now i found a way to get that what i want, but its using the FQL:

```
SELECT message
FROM stream
WHERE source_id = <ourID>
AND strpos(lower(message), "#keyword") >= 0;
```

I heard that the FQL is going to be removed soon. So is there a way to convert this FQL into the Facebook graph API?

Comment: Nobody has an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As solution i just gather all the data and filter them by myself via CRON-Job.